# How tensorflow2 gets intermediate layer output

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I want to use tensorflow2 to achieve cnn extraction of image features and then output to SVM for classification. What are the good ways?
I have checked the documentation of tensorflow2 and there is no good explanation. Who can guide me?

Comment: To make sure I understand your use case, can I ask the following questions? 1) What API of tensorflow2 are you using for the layers and the model? Are you using `tf.keras.*`? 2) How is the SVM implemented? Are you using an SVM implementation from something like scikit learn,  from tensorflow itself, or from something else?

Comment: I try to build the network using like this
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(384, 512)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
])

Comment: I use SVM in sklearn

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your clarifying answers above. I have written answers to similar questions before. But you can extract intermediate-layer outputs from a tf.keras model by constructing an auxiliary model using the so called **functional model API**. "Function model API" uses [tf.keras.Model()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=stable). When you call the function, you specify the arguments `inputs` and `outputs`. You can include the output of the intermediate layer in the `outputs` argument. See the simple code example below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# This is the original model.
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28, 1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")])

# Make an auxiliary model that exposes the output from the intermediate layer
# of interest, which is the first Dense layer in this case.
aux_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs,
                           outputs=model.outputs + [model.layers[1].output])

# Access both the final and intermediate output of the original model
# by calling `aux_model.predict()`.
final_output, intermediate_layer_output = aux_model.predict(some_input)
```